# Appcelerator Studio does nothing

Tags: appcelerator

3 issues !!!

Sometimes, it has java.lang.NullPointerException

Windows 8.1 (64 bit)
jdk1.7.0_80 (32 bit)

Studio start. But File > New > Mobile App Project does nothing.

Android Studio working perfectly fine. From Appcelerator, Preferences > Studio > Platforms > Android > Android SDK Home

Point to either Appcelerator SDK folder C:\android-sdk-win or

Android SDK folder C:\Users\test\dev\Android\sdk

None of those work. Which mean, it cannot change SDK folder !!!

Comment: Start by posting one issue. If you're getting `NullPointerException` it means that you've already configured the JDK correctly - so the rest of your question is unclear. As for the NPR - you should provide more details: your code, full stacktrace, which line triggers the error and etc.

Comment: I do not have a chance to line a line of code. I want to create a Mobile App Project. I click on File > New > Mobile App Project.

Then I wait. IDE does not show any error or any message. It just does not do anything.

Comment: that's not enough information... Sounds like environment issue, try to close/open your IDE and if that doesn't work - reinstall the whole thing.

Comment: I reinstall it. I remove and reinstall JDK, put path too.

Create a Linux and Wins 8 VM with virtualbox, follow instruction from Appcelerator. NOTHING WORK !

Finally I have to give up. It work on Wins 7 and I wrote a simple app on Win7 but right now I don't have Wins 7.

*** I do not see any stack so I have no idea where to look for more info and THAT is the most annoying part ****

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: The JDK needs to be 32bit whether windows running 32 or 64 bit. Did you set JAVA_HOME? If not, please take a look : [JAVA_HOME variable](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Oracle_JDK)

Issue 2: Run the following command in the administrative command prompt.

​
**npm uninstall -g appcelerator**

**npm install -g appcelerator**

**appc setup**

**appc use latest**

Issue 3:

[Configuring Studio](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK-section-src-29004851_InstallingtheAndroidSDK-ConfiguringtheCLI)